# Can't add to cart some specific products in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

IN WooCommerce, I'm having a problem on one product https://red-strawberry.onyx-sites.io/product/rigid-card-holder-portrait-cr80-pack-of-100/. I can't add it to cart. The other products are doing just fine and only this product isn't.

Any suggestion?

Comment: To be honest, I think you have other (more important) issues on your server. It takes a lot of time to load and this message appeared: "The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Comment: I was trying to fix it then I have server error. Now it's working again

Answer (score 0):

You can not **remove** other attribute.

you **Just hide** the attribute using css.

please edit this product and remove attribute from variation section and try it.

**Please refer screenshot**

https://prnt.sc/10p25aw

I have checked all your variation products and same issue is occurring in each variation product.

so if you use only color attribute then remove other attribute

Comment: I want to remove/hide specific attributes globally. is there a way to do that? Because i have hundreds of product idont want to do it one by one

Comment: If you are not use anywhere this attribute then remove globally. In admin menu Products -> Attributes

Comment: I still want the attribute there. but I just don't want to show it onsite

Comment: then import product csv and remove attribute column of data and export it. OR directly Run query on database.

Comment: Your question is not clear. you are taking about only one product. not all product please edit your question. also mention all issue. otherwise you never get proper answer.

Comment: I want to import via CSV (With attributes on) but I dont want to display every attribute on the page (for example on this page, I only want to see colour variable). Some says that i need to add function on fucntion.php file